# Why doesn't padding-bottom work with inline-block?

Tags: html, css

I am working on creating a playlist display from our YouTube videos. I thought I had this working, but I am having some issues with how it displays. See code below.

If I used `display: block` the paragraph is next to the video like I want, but I can't add any padding after the video so that the videos don't together. When I use `display: inline-block` I can control the bottom padding, but then some videos will display next to each other.

What am I missing in my CSS?

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL_roY9OMKxXPoliYn_2D4t1LeoFdLpiEA?v=2&alt=json",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(json) {
          var entries = json.feed.entry;

          for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
            $('#vidBox').append('<div class="videoElem"><h3>' + entries[i].title.$t + '</h3><div class="ytVideo"><iframe width="300" height="225" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + entries[i].media$group.yt$videoid.$t + '?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div><p>' + entries[i].media$group.media$description.$t + '</p></div>');
          }
        }
      });
    });
```

```css
    .videoElem {
      display: block;
      clear: both;
      padding-bottom: 25px;
    }
    .ytVideo iframe {
      float: left;
      padding-right: 10px;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 648px) {
      .ytVideo iframe {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="vidBox"></div>
```

Comment: Could you post the relevant bit of code here as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to `inline-block` you can make it `width:100%` to stop multiple videos from appearing on the same line.

```
.videoElem {
    display: inline-block;
    width:100%;
}
```

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, I didn't think to add 100% width. The intricacies of CSS is where I struggle. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem! You get used to it after a while

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are clearing the floats incorrectly. You can

- Use `clear: both` on an element after the floats, but not to the container.

  ```css
  .videoElem:after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
  ```

  ```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL_roY9OMKxXPoliYn_2D4t1LeoFdLpiEA?v=2&alt=json",
      cache: false,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      success: function (json) {
        var entries = json.feed.entry;

        for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
          $('#vidBox').append('<div class="videoElem"><h3>' + entries[i].title.$t + '</h3><div class="ytVideo"><iframe width="300" height="225" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + entries[i].media$group.yt$videoid.$t + '?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div><p>' + entries[i].media$group.media$description.$t + '</p></div>');
        }
      }
    });
  });
  ```

  ```css
  .videoElem {
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
  }
  .videoElem:after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
  .ytVideo iframe {
    float: left;
    padding-right:10px;
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width : 648px) {
    .ytVideo iframe {
      width:100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div id="vidBox"></div>
  ```
- Use `overflow` different than `visible` on the container:

  ```css
  .videoElem {
      overflow: hidden;
  }
  ```

  ```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL_roY9OMKxXPoliYn_2D4t1LeoFdLpiEA?v=2&alt=json",
      cache: false,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      success: function (json) {
        var entries = json.feed.entry;

        for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
          $('#vidBox').append('<div class="videoElem"><h3>' + entries[i].title.$t + '</h3><div class="ytVideo"><iframe width="300" height="225" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + entries[i].media$group.yt$videoid.$t + '?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div><p>' + entries[i].media$group.media$description.$t + '</p></div>');
        }
      }
    });
  });
  ```

  ```css
  .videoElem {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
  }
  .ytVideo iframe {
    float: left;
    padding-right:10px;
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width : 648px) {
    .ytVideo iframe {
      width:100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div id="vidBox"></div>
  ```